# Winter 15 preview new error messages: valueOf() function

Tags: visualforce, controller, error-messages, winter15

We have been experiencing serious issues today with the release of Winter 15 into our sandboxes...

> Salesforce System Error: 1702643372-49547 (938791604) (938791604)
>   Error is in expression '{!initSearchCatalogPage}' in component
>    in page findlearning:
>   Class.SearchCatalogController.makeFullModuleList: line 114, column 1
>   Class.SearchCatalogController.initSearchCatalogPage: line 50, column 1
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has
>   been notified.

The line numbers are both wrong (the functionality is 1 line earlier in both cases. Troubling thing is... nothing has changed in this area for a while.

Comment: Can you re-phrase this to say that it is a preview of Winter 15 - release schedule is here https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/. You should create a case quoting the error numbers you are getting as Salesforce support can typically access more debug log information using those numbers. That also improves the odds that the problem will be fixed or have a work-around when the release is done.

Comment: Edit done and case was previously created

Comment: Thanks; I know the wait can be frustrating. If `initSearchCatalogPage` is simple enough perhaps adding it to your question might improve the chances of someone who has experienced the same problem answering.

Comment: I found the issue: there has been a change to the way that integer.valueof() handles NULL values.

This line: decimal.valueOf(integer.valueof(mod.get('Average_Ratings__c'))) no longer works but this
decimal.valueOf(0) is a good work around if mod.get('Average_Ratings__c') = NULL

Comment: It's not just Integer.valueOf... there are now plenty more places where valueOf used to return null but now throws an exception. This has caught me off-guard, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There has been a change to the way that integer.valueof() handles NULL values.

This line: 
decimal.valueOf(integer.valueof(mod.get('Average_Ratings__c'))) no longer works

but this:
decimal.valueOf(0) is a good work around if mod.get('Average_Ratings__c') = NULL

Comment: In your question you say "nothing has changed" so by that do you include the version number of the class that is seeing the new behaviour? If so that seems like a gross failure of the platform's API versioning. Can you confirm one way or the other?

Comment: This class is using version 25 of the API: 
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>25.0</apiVersion>

Comment: Well that is pretty bad then. (I also don't see any mention of this change in https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter15_release_notes.pdf.)

Comment: @KeithC in my experience api version don't mean squat for under the cover changes